# PHP different memory_get_usage() on different servers

Tags: php

I am running a script using CLI on 2 servers, both script are identical.

memory_get_usage(true) returns 786432 on first server
memory_get_usage(true) returns 1572864 on 2nd server

What could make this difference ?

Comment: 32bit architecture vs 64bit?

Comment: Are they running the same version of PHP? The same libraries used by PHP? Etc, etc.. lots of things could factor in here.

Comment: different SO, different architecture, different Apache version, different php version, etc. etc.?

Comment: Thanks @zerkms, i just noticed the first server is 32, the other is 64.

Comment: @ChrisHayes  yes same apache and php versions, same modules loaded, same everything, the 2 servers are identical except for the architecture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comments: exactly 2x difference points to different architectures: 32bit vs 64bit.